# unable to see reporting services in datatools

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

iam unable to see business intelligence tab
can you please help me out what i have to install i order i can see this tab

[image]iam new to SSRS and creating new project using SQL server datatools
though in setup i can se of sql server that reporting service is installed.
but iam not able to find on visual stuio

[image]

error where it get stops 
[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused, that image you've supplied **is** from Visual Studio. That implies you do have it installed. Or is that image not from your PC?

Comment: i have installed though image its just to convey i cant see those tabs

Comment: above is image from my system where i cant see tabs

Comment: Looks like you haven't installed SSDT. What version of SQL Server, and Visual Studio, do you have?

Comment: sql server 2016 and visual studio 2015

Comment: tried installaing SSDT its giving unspecified error, some registry keys are missing  like Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\14.0\premium' Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\14.0\professional'  Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\14.0\enterprise'

Comment: Which SSDT are you using? You should be using the one found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt#ssdt-for-visual-studio-2015) under **SSDT for Visual Studio 2015**. Also, when installing, ensure you are running the setup file as Administrator.

Comment: yes iam using same which you gave but its giving error which i shown above in log file

Comment: And you're running the install as Adminsitrator..?

Comment: yes iam running with administrator it runs and stop at microsoft application language support 2015 and throws error and stops

Comment: Try restarting the machine; might be that you have pending updates/installs. Google, however, seems to imply the reason is you're not running as administrator (Right Click -> Run as Adminstrator).

Comment: did but googled its saying uninstalls vs/ssdt 2015 and install again

Comment: You can download and use report builder to create ssrs reports. here is the link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53613